# create EMR cluster with Autotermination setting using Airflows [CreateEMRJobFlowOperator]

Tags: amazon-web-services, airflow, amazon-emr, botocore

I'm trying to create EMR cluster with Autotermination Idle timeout setting using Airflow DAG.

It doesn't accept Autoterminationpolicy parameter and fails with parameter validation with following error:

```
raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())
botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "AutoTerminationPolicy", must be one of: Name, LogUri, LogEncryptionKmsKeyId, AdditionalInfo, AmiVersion, ReleaseLabel, Instances, Steps, BootstrapActions, SupportedProducts, NewSupportedProducts, Applications, Configurations, VisibleToAllUsers, JobFlowRole, ServiceRole, Tags, SecurityConfiguration, AutoScalingRole, ScaleDownBehavior, CustomAmiId, EbsRootVolumeSize, RepoUpgradeOnBoot, KerberosAttributes, StepConcurrencyLevel, ManagedScalingPolicy, PlacementGroupConfigs
```

```
JOB_FLOW_OVERRIDES = {
    'Name': 'X',
    'ReleaseLabel': "{{ReleaseLabel}}",
    "Applications": [{"Name": "Hadoop"}, {"Name": "Spark"}, {"Name": "Hive"}],
    "AutoTerminationPolicy": { 
      "IdleTimeout": 60 * 10
      },
    'LogUri': LogUri,
    'Instances': {
        'Ec2SubnetId': "{{Ec2SubnetId}}",
        'EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup': "{{EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup}}",
        'ServiceAccessSecurityGroup': "{{ServiceAccessSecurityGroup}}",
        'EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup': "{{EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup}}",
        'InstanceGroups': [
```

Comment: Did you try with a value of 600 instead of 60 * 10 for IdleTimeout?

Comment: tried but no luck :(

Comment: It's clearly mention that AutoTerminationPolicy  itself is not in the permitted list of setting.

Comment: botocore.exceptions.ParamValidationError: Parameter validation failed:
Unknown parameter in input: "AutoTerminationPolicy", must be one of: Name, LogUri, LogEncryptionKmsKeyId, AdditionalInfo, AmiVersion, ReleaseLabel, Instances, Steps, BootstrapActions, SupportedProducts, NewSupportedProducts, Applications, Configurations, VisibleToAllUsers, JobFlowRole, ServiceRole, Tags, SecurityConfiguration, AutoScalingRole, ScaleDownBehavior, CustomAmiId, EbsRootVolumeSize, RepoUpgradeOnBoot, KerberosAttributes, StepConcurrencyLevel, ManagedScalingPolicy, PlacementGroupConfigs

Answer (score 0):

hmm, I also got similar error message (Unknown parameter in input: "IdleTimeout"), but when I try this, it works:

```
'AutoTerminationPolicy': 
  { 
      'IdleTimeout': 600
  },
```

Perhaps try use ' instead of " ?